# Update SQL Query for varchar(max) column

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

How to update a `varchar(max)` column to an empty string from null value?

Here is the pseudo code:

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET all varchar(max) columns ='' 
WHERE varchar(max) == NULL
```

Need to create something like this, any help will be appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please use this. **where ColumnName IS NULL** for NULL comparison equal does not work with default ANSI_NULLS.

ColumnName -> VARCHAR(MAX)

```
Update tablename 
SET field ='' 
where ColumnName IS NULL
```

Comment: I need to update the ALL varchar(max) field value into string.empty  in a table

Comment: For example I need to update all the varchar(max) fields into string.empty. in a single Table.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding this question, When you gonna Update the column try to put the empty string inside the quotes 
You can check this code hopefully you will get the Idea

```
UPDATE Table_Name (v VARCHAR(4))
SET ('  ')
WHERE condition;
```

Output

```
SELECT CONCAT ('(', v, ')') FROM Table_Name;

| CONCAT('(', v, ')')


| (  )
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to `UPDATE` to all row which has null values use ANSI SQL `COALESCE()` function

```
UPDATE tablename 
SET 
     Column = COALESCE(Column, ''), Column1 = COALESCE(Column1, ''),  
     ....
     Column4 = COALESCE(Column4, '')
```

Since use of `COALESCE()`, it would just update the column values to blank where  it found the null values.